# What is the point of private

Tags: c++

What's the purpose of the purpose of the private modifier if you can a create union that contains the class and a struct with the same variables from the class?

```
class SecretClass {
    public:
        int a = 12;
        int b = 64;
    private:
        int c = 2138;
        int d = 8789;
};

union Access {
    SecretClass secret;
    struct {
        int a,b,c,d;
    };
};

int main() {
    SecretClass secret;
    Access access{ secret };
    std::cout << access.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << access.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << access.c << std::endl;
    std::cout << access.d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior to read from an inactive memory of a union. Your code only seems to work by accident and you cannot rely on this.

Comment: Besides the undefined behavior, try doing something more complicated with `SecretClass`, like giving it a constructor. You'll find that you can't put it in a union anymore.

Comment: More of, class looses standard layout with access modifier appearing, so any other way to "pun" it via similar structure defaults to UB

Comment: You can always access any bit in memory, if you have physical access to the machine and the right equipment and enough time, expertise, and money. The purpose of `private` isn't to enforce security. It's to communicate design intention to whoever is using your class that they shouldn't touch those parts of it.

Comment: Access control is not about security. It’s about maintainability.

Comment: The big mistake seems to be to ask the other question "_if you can..._".

Comment: @Kevin "*try doing something more complicated with `SecretClass`, like giving it a constructor. You'll find that you can't put it in a union anymore*" - you can in C++11 and later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access specifiers are not there to enforce access. They are there to prevent wrong use of the class's API by accident. There are multiple ways to get around them, but doing so by accident is virtually impossible.

In other words, everything that's `private` in a class says "you *should not* access these". It doesn't say "you *can not* access these."

Answer (score 0):

It's purpose to define visibility of names.

Any action like one you propose may fail with another compiler, because compilers guarantee behaviour with rules defined by standard. You can use union that way only for trivial classes with common starting sequence, presence of access modifier breaks that rule.